Can a firmware file be edited after it is compiled?
So I know exe files can be edited with something like x64dbg, but are there any tools that can be used to edit firmware upgrade files. Specifically the format is .spff and it is a firmware upgrade file for a solar inverter.
I would like to enable debug mode for the inverter so the setup menu can be accessed over a local isolated ethernet connection.
If I try to open the .spff file in notepad, there are some strings near the beginning of the file, but past that it is not human readable. x64dbg can only open exe and dll files, to my knowledge.

Can you replace an assemble call with another assemble call, in some cases you can, but the binary would no longer match the checksum if you did that and that is often a check to verify the firmware load was completed.  You would have to way more specific to answer this question with a meaningful answer.

Could it be edited? Yes, but would it work afterwards? Likely not -- and worse, it might brick a system so that further updates to fixed the borked firmware would fail. You might contact the inverter manufacturer to ask for help. Does the current firmware support Ethernet or WiFi?

@DrMoishePippik Yes the firmware supports both ethernet and wifi, but the setup menu can only be accessed through ethernet on initial setup. Then the port is blocked. Logging data can still be accessed through ethernet. It is a SolarEdge inverter. SolarEdge support is practically non-existent and of no help even for installers, unless you are a top level installer who does millions of dollars a year with them. I am a installer, but they wont help me. This is on my personal system, so i am aware of the risks and will not be risking anyone else's equipement.

It seems particularly pernicious that a company would purposely block Ethernet so that one must use WiFi. It leaves a security hole which allows remote control by a malefactor -- or even by the company, should they wish to brick the device, as HP has done to printers after supply contracts were not renewed. Might a Raspberry Pi be used is a mobile hotspot, making a closed WiFi system??

@DrMoishePippik The Wi-Fi is blocked as well after initial setup except for monitoring communications. Basically after initial setup, it blocks all ports except the one(s) used to transmit the monitoring data. The setup pages are only ever accessible by toggling a switch on the exterior of the inverter. It temporarily enables a wifi AP and turns off after a few mins of no device connected. It also has a cellular card that can transmit monitoring data if ethernet or wifi is not available, but i didnt think that was relevant
